# Why is the output Loop 3, Loop 2, Loop 1, Loop 1?

Tags: c#, recursion, methods, while-loop

For the following code, I was expecting the Console to output

```
Loop 3
Loop 2
Loop 1
```

However, instead

```
Loop 3
Loop 2
Loop 1
Loop 1
```

is displayed.
I understand it is a recursive method i.e. calling itself. Just struggling to to understand how it works. This is an exam question which I struggled with.

I've tried to Debug and I see the following occur:

1. After i iterates down to 0, it comes out of the while loop as expected
2. It runs the return Lemmings - 1; statement at which point i'd have thought Lemmings would equate to -1, but instead it goes back to the line i = WriteToConsole(i - 1); which is executed
3. Somehow Lemmings = 1 and i = -1
4. It continues but I'm lost at this point

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WhileLoopExample
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int WriteToConsole(int Lemmings)
        {
            int i = Lemmings;
            while (i > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("loop {0}", i);
                i = WriteToConsole(i - 1);
            }
            return Lemmings - 1;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WriteToConsole(3);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mix recursion with iteration. The duration of your iteration (number of loop iterations) depend on the given Lemming value as well as on the return value of WriteToConsole. However, the return value of WriteToConsole itself does not depend on further recursive calls of WriteToConsole, but only on the Lemmings argument that is not changed within the method. Perhaps it will be easier for you to understand if you draw the flow of your program visually on paper as a flow chart ....

Comment: You don't have to go down that rabbit hole very deep to see what is going on. Just look at when you call WriteToConsole the first time with Lemmings = 3. Now, the first recursive call of WriteToConsole will have its Lemmings argument set to 2, resulting in it returning the value `1`. Try to understand that. Now, while the recursive call of WriteToConsole (and further recursive calls further down the rabbit hole) print out "Loop 2" and 
"Loop 1", the return value of `1` for the very first recursive call causes an additional print of "Loop 1".

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you do not understand the notion of *function activation*.  Every activation of the function has its own copy of `i` and its own copy of `Lemmings`, and these are *completely independent* of every other function activation.

What is messing you up here is that you have **five** -- yes five -- different calls to `WriteToConsole`, and all of them have their *own* copy of `i` and their *own* copy of `lemmings`.  Let's illustrate that by instrumenting your program to show each different function activation and what the values of each variable are at each point:

```
public class Program
{
    private static int callCount = 0;
    private static int WriteToConsole(int lemmings)
    {
        callCount += 1;
        int currentCall = callCount;

        Console.WriteLine("Call number {0} has Lemmings = {1}", currentCall, lemmings);
        int i = lemmings;
        Console.WriteLine("Call number {0} has i = {1}", currentCall, i);
        while (i > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Call number {0} in the loop top with i = {1}", currentCall, i);
            i = WriteToConsole(i - 1);
            Console.WriteLine("Call number {0} in the loop bottom with i = {1}", currentCall, i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Call number {0} is about to return {1}", currentCall, lemmings - 1);
        return lemmings - 1;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WriteToConsole(3);
    }
}
```

Now we can see the output reflects what is happening:

```
Call number 1 has Lemmings = 3
Call number 1 has i = 3
Call number 1 in the loop top with i = 3
Call number 2 has Lemmings = 2
Call number 2 has i = 2
Call number 2 in the loop top with i = 2
Call number 3 has Lemmings = 1
Call number 3 has i = 1
Call number 3 in the loop top with i = 1
Call number 4 has Lemmings = 0
Call number 4 has i = 0
Call number 4 is about to return -1
Call number 3 in the loop bottom with i = -1
Call number 3 is about to return 0
Call number 2 in the loop bottom with i = 0
Call number 2 is about to return 1
Call number 1 in the loop bottom with i = 1
Call number 1 in the loop top with i = 1
Call number 5 has Lemmings = 0
Call number 5 has i = 0
Call number 5 is about to return -1
Call number 1 in the loop bottom with i = -1
Call number 1 is about to return 2
```

Read the trace *very carefully* until you understand what is going on. You get *four* outputs of `loop x` because call number 1 is in the loop top when `i` is 3, and after the recursive call, `i` is 1. The loop condition is met, so call 1 prints both `loop 3` and `loop 1`.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Your answer allows me to debug and understand this better.
I should have clarified, this is an exam question that I struggled with. Couldn't find much on the web to help me understand, maybe i'm not searching for the right thing (tried recursion and while loop examples). Much appreciate your effort and time.

Comment: @Enzo: Right, I figured this was probably a homework problem or something; that's why all the people who told you "you're doing it wrong" were unhelpful.  You are very welcome. Recursion can be tricky to reason about.

Answer (score 2):

In your recursive call, you pass in `i - 1`. That becomes `Lemmings` - which you return as `Lemmings - 1`.

There are two `-1`s happening - is that what you want?

But if you look at what’s happening:

- The first call has `Lemmings` as `3` and `i` as `3`.

  `Loop 3` is written out.

  Then recursion happens, passing in `3-1`:

  - The second call has `Lemmings` as `2` and `i` as `2`.

    `Loop 2` is written out.

    Then recursion happens, passing in `2-1`:

    - The third call has `Lemmings` as `1` and `i` as `1`.

      `Loop 1` is written out.

      Then recursion happens, passing in `1-1`:

      - The fourth call has `Lemmings` as `0` and `i` as `0`.

        The `while` is not entered, so `0-1` is returned.
    - Back inside the third call:

      `i` is assigned `-1`, so the while finishes.

      The third call returns `1-1`.
  - Back inside the second call:

    `i` is assigned `0`, so the while finishes.

    The second call returns `2-1`.
- Back inside the first call:

  `i` is assigned `1`, so the while continues.

  `Loop 1` is written out.

The execution continues from here, but all without output. The above is why you get two `Loop 1`s.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have a loop *and* you have recursion. You should get rid of the call to `WriteToConsole(i)` inside `WriteToConsole`, or get rid of the loop and stick with recursion.

Moreover, you use the return value of the recursive call to influence `i` and therefore your `while` loop. I think this causes the main deal of your confusion.

Fortunately it's only a couple of steps, so it can be broken down quite easily. This is what happens. The while loop is implied, I just describe output, modifications to i, and recursive calls.

```
You call WriteToConsole(3); // Let's call this 'instance' of the function call 'A'
  A prints "Loop 3"
  A calls WriteToConsole(2); // Let's call this 'B'
    B prints "Loop 2"
    B calls WriteToConsole(1) // Let's call this 'C'
      C prints "Loop 1"
      C calls WriteToConsole(0); // Let's call this 'D'
        D doesn't enter it's loop. 
        D returns -1 (Lemmings - 1, where Lemmings is 0), i becomes -1 in C
      C's loop ends because i is -1
      C returns 0, i becomes 0 in B
    B's loop ends, because i is 0
    B returns 1, i becomes 1 in A
  A is still in the loop, since its 'i' > 0, so..
  A prints "Loop 1" (again)
  A calls WriteToConsole(0); // Let's call this 'E'
    E returns -1, i becomes -1 in A
  A returns 2, this value is ignored in your main function.
End of program
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is really helpful. Especially with the Letters and indentation. I now understand much better

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, in this case you need **one loop or other iteration mechanism**, either by means of recursion (without a `while`), or by means of a `while` (but then without recursion).

Here is the solution for the `while` without recursion:

```
private static void WriteToConsole(int Lemmings)
{
    int i = Lemmings;
    while (i > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("loop {0}", i);
        i = i - 1; // Decrease i, no need for recursion here
    }
}
```

Working DotNetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kR4th0

Comment: It wasn't me, I swear ;-)

Comment: Thanks for responding Peter, it is an exam question. I have now updated the post.